# How to use same field multiple times in MongoDB find query in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with records having a `"name"` field, I am trying to perform a find query where the name field appears twice in the query. I want to exclude certain names, via `$nin`, and perform regex search for other names. It doesn't seem to be working, as it returns all records. If I just have the regex search or the `$nin` search, it works as expected.

`db.users.find({name:{$nin:[current_user]}).cb(array)` - works

`db.users.find({name:new RegExp(/query/)}).cb(array)` - works

`db.users.find({name:{$nin:[current_user]}, name:new RegExp(/query/)}).cb(array)` - does NOT work, the current_user is NOT excluded from the find result.

I have a feeling, the find command takes the last query for multiple occurrences of the same field, is that so? And how do I get around it?

Thanks for help,
Gary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your query JSON object contains `name` field two times, and it breaks the query. Pay attention to the [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) mongo query operator. There are two ways to construct correct query:

**1)** `db.users.find({ $and: [{ name: { $nin: [current_user] } }, { name: { $regex: new RegExp(/query/) } }] })`

**2)** `db.users.find({ name: { $nin: [current_user], $regex: new RegExp(/query/) } })`

Also, if you exclude only one user, you can use [`$ne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator instead of `$nin`.

Comment: I was under the impression that comma separated list of key:value pairs in the find command is the equivalent of doing the AND operation, but I guess NOT when the field is used multiple times. Thank You.

Comment: yes, comma separated is the correct way to do it.  Using $and is not the correct way to do it.  so 1) is not the way to do it, 2) is, except your regex syntax is wrong.

Comment: 1) But why so? I've run such query on simple test data and it gave me expected results. Also [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) say that "If, however, a query requires an AND operation on the same field such as `{ price: { $ne: 1.99 } }` AND `{ price: { $exists: true } }`, then either use the `$and` operator for the two separate expressions or combine the operator expressions for the field `{ price: { $ne: 1.99, $exists: true } }`". Maybe I miss something?         2) Thank you for point out this mistake! I've corrected it.